# Download .EXE file via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I do a function, that allow do the download of a file in C:  ?

For example, when the link is clicked, trigger a javascript function that will open the file or made download.

I'm trying this,

But it execute the program, I need that execute a download!

```
   if (url == "Supremo") {
       var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
       var prog = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\admin.redenetimoveis.com\\San\\up\\arquivos\\Supremo.exe";               
       oShell.run('"' + prog + '"', 1);
       return false;
   }
```

Comment: Does navigating to the file work?

Comment: You've got to clarify what you want, before you get negativity!

Comment: are you trying to run the file or are you trying to get the user to download it?

Comment: @JohnP I need that the user download it!

Comment: `$.post('samples1.exe', function() {
    //after file download
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a user to download an exe file, you simply need to point them to the url with something like

```
window.location = 'http://admin.redenetimoveis.com/Supremo.exe';
```

As per the comment below, simply make an `anchor` tag that points to the file:

```
<a href="http://admin.redenetimoveis.com/Supremo.exe">Download Executable</a>
```

Comment: Is just serve the file to my user download it, when click in my link

Comment: @Lucas_Santos Is your server setup to allow the download of a `.exe` file?

Comment: You need to make sure that the file is in an accessible folder on your server.  Also, what server are you using?

Comment: I got it now!, sorry. I'm trying to put the C:\ path instead, it will never works because of the security settings, but I put like you said, in a accessible folder an it works fine!, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden iframe with a src attribute pointing to the file that needs to be downloaded. Keep in mind, however, that the src value needs to be a file that is accessible to the client, such as going to a domain. `http://www.somedomain.com/thefile.exe`